# Load HTML content without external resources into an iframe

Tags: html, iframe

How can I only load the HTML of a page into an `<iframe>`, without automatically triggering the download of all the CSS, scripts, images and videos on the page?

Answer (score 1):

In short: you cannot. Much like you cannot "load an HTML page in a browser" without making the browser load all the linked resources (images, stylesheets). It's up to the browser how it implements its `iframe`s, but most browsers treat them like embedded separate websites that are treated just like ordinary websites in terms of loading linked resources.

What is it you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for u r answer. I have a button and when u click the button, it will load the html content(local drive path,i.e ../html/text1.html) in an iframe()